# Finite multisets as a HIT in Cubical Agda

Tags: proof, agda, multiset, homotopy-type-theory, cubical-type-theory

In the standard library of Cubical Agda, there are [finite multisets](https://github.com/agda/cubical/tree/master/Cubical/HITs/FiniteMultiset) whose elegant definitions I reproduce below:

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical --safe #-}

open import Cubical.Foundations.Prelude

infixr 20 _∷_

data FMSet (A : Set) : Set where
  []    : FMSet A
  _∷_   : (x : A) → (xs : FMSet A) → FMSet A
  comm  : ∀ x y xs → x ∷ y ∷ xs ≡ y ∷ x ∷ xs
  trunc : isSet (FMSet A)

_++_ : ∀ {A : Set} -> FMSet A → FMSet A → FMSet A
[] ++ ys = ys
(x ∷ xs) ++ ys = x ∷ (xs ++ ys)
comm x y xs i ++ ys = comm x y (xs ++ ys) i
trunc xs1 xs2 p q i j ++ ys =
  trunc (xs1 ++ ys) (xs2 ++ ys) (cong (_++ ys) p) (cong (_++ ys) q) i j
```

The proof that `[]` is a right-neutral element uses the abstract lemma `FMSetElimProp.f` which I do not understand. Therefore I am trying to make a direct proof, but I am stuck. Here is my attempts:

```
unitr-++ : ∀ {A : Set} (ys : FMSet A) → ys ++ [] ≡ ys
unitr-++ [] = refl
unitr-++ (y ∷ ys) = cong ((y ∷_)) (unitr-++ ys)
unitr-++ (comm x y xs i) = cong₂ {!comm x y!} (unitr-++ xs) refl
unitr-++ (trunc xs1 xs2 p q i j) = {!!}
```

Am I on the right track? How can I finish this proof?

Comment: As I understand it, you need to provide a path between paths in the last two clauses there. However, you already have an assertion that `FMSet` is a set (i.e. homotopy level 0), so all equalities are equal (all paths have paths between them). `FMSetElimProp` is a proof of this fact. So you can use it anywhere you need an equality between equalities of `FMSet`s.

Comment: @oisdk You interpretation of `FMSetElimProp.f` is very impressive! Unfortunately, I must be very stupid because I only see a complicated statement there. Could you elaborate in an answer how you arrive at this interpretation?

Comment: I haven't put an answer because I'm not sure of how correct I am!

Comment: But basically: in the `comm` clause of the `unitr-++` function, you need to provide an equality of equalities. You can prove this manually (as far as I know), but since you've already specified that `FMSet` is h-level 0 (that's what adding the `trunc` constructor to the type does), you don't have to, since all equalities of h-level 0 types are automatically equal. So you just provide a proof of that fact (which is proven already in the cubical library), which is called `FMSetElimProp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two SO questions that answer this are [this one for `comm`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653766/477476) and [this one for `trunc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57800552/477476). Like you, I've struggled with the same frustration: if all these types are `Set`s, why do I need to write ANYTHING, let alone something complicated, to prove some 2-paths?!?!

So, first of all, from the first linked answer, let's start at

```
comm x y xs i ++ ys = ?
```

and ask Agda what is the type of the hole.

> Goal: `comm x y (xs ++ []) i ≡ comm x y xs i`

Well that sounds promising because we know that `comm x y (xs ++ []) ≡ comm x y xs` simply by `xs + [] ≡ xs` inductively. So, let's ask what exactly that would buy us. Put `cong (comm x y) (unitr-++ xs)` in the hole and ask for its type:

> Have:
>
> ```
> PathP
>      (λ i → x ∷ y ∷ unitr-++ xs i ≡ y ∷ x ∷ unitr-++ xs i)
>      (comm x y (xs ++ [])) (comm x y xs)
> ```

Then @Saizan's answer instructs us to produce the `Square` with exactly these faces:

```
isSet→isSet' trunc
  (comm x y (xs ++ []))
  (comm x y xs)
  (λ j → x ∷ y ∷ unitr-++ xs i)
  (λ j → y ∷ x ∷ unitr-++ xs i)
```

and choose the right internal point on it, giving us the filling of our hole:

```
unitr-++ (comm x y xs i) j = isSet→isSet' trunc
  (comm x y (xs ++ []))
  (comm x y xs)
  (λ j → x ∷ y ∷ unitr-++ xs j)
  (λ j → y ∷ x ∷ unitr-++ xs j)
  j i
```

For the second missing clause, i.e. in

```
unitr-++ (trunc xs1 xs2 p q i j)
```

following the linked answer's recommendation, we can ask Agda for the faces of the cube we want to construct:

```
r : Cube ? ? ? ? ? ?
r = cong (cong unitr-++) (trunc xs1 xs2 p q)
```

By using `C-c C-s` in all six face holes, Agda tells us:

```
r : Cube (λ i j → trunc xs1 xs2 p q i j ++ [])
         (λ i j → unitr-++ xs1 j)
         (λ i j → unitr-++ xs2 j)
         (λ i j → trunc xs1 xs2 p q i j)
         (λ i j → unitr-++ (p i) j)
         (λ i j → unitr-++ (q i) j)
```

so now we know exactly which cube to construct (using the fact that `Set`s are also `Groupoid`s, as witnessed by `hLevelSuc 2 _`):

```
unitr-++ (trunc xs1 xs2 p q i j) = isGroupoid→isGroupoid' (hLevelSuc 2 _ trunc)
  (λ i j → trunc xs1 xs2 p q i j ++ [])
  (λ i j → unitr-++ xs1 j)
  (λ i j → unitr-++ xs2 j)
  (λ i j → trunc xs1 xs2 p q i j)
  (λ i j → unitr-++ (p i) j)
  (λ i j → unitr-++ (q i) j)
  i
  j
```

By now, on one hand, we can be happy that we're done, but on the other hand, we are pissed off because this answer was all "look at this other answer and do exactly that", "look at this other answer and do exactly that", but surely if you can do EXACTLY that, even though your type, and your function, and your function property, are NOT the same as mine was when I asked my original question, then there is something that should be abstracted away here, right?

And **that** is what [`FMSetElimProp`](https://github.com/agda/cubical/blob/0ddad3448aacb00e82eba29a8bf225414bab4832/Cubical/HITs/FiniteMultiset/Base.agda#L35) does. It implements ALL this machinery above, for `FMSet` specifically, but for all functions and all properties of those functions, in one fell swoop. So you DON'T have to look at this answer and the two linked ones and do all this OVER and OVER and OVER again, when in fact at the end it shouldn't make a difference anyway since all the constructed paths are path-equivalent anyway.